# how to clear buffer cache in postgres that hosted in aws rds?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-rds

i have a aws rds postgres instance and i want to clear the query result cache so that I can get the real performance time for a particular query. When I first run the query it took more than 1 mins and then timeout but after that the first request the result came within 1 sec.